# Show/Hide divs that occupy the same space with separate links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with trying to get divs to occupy the same space, and to also have a show/hide ability on them when clicking their respective links.

Can anybody please let me know the proper jQuery to put in to make this happen? Below is the code without jQuery.

The idea is that when I click on Print 1, then the piece #1 will show up, and when I click Print 2, #1 will disappear and #2 will take it's place.

Current HTML looks something vaguely like this:

```
<div id="content">

    <div id="SideNav">                  
       <ul>
          <li>
            <a>Print 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Print 2</a>
          </li>             
       </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="pieces">
       <div id="1">
       </div>
       <div id="2">
       </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

CSS is basically this:

```
#content {
    width:848px;
    position:relative;
}

#SideNav {
    width:169px;
    float:left;
}

#pieces  {
    width:678px;
    top:0px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}

#1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index:1;
}

#2 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Are your elements dynamic? or just static?

Comment: Just static. The divs #1 and #2 would just have static text and images in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to make your markup structure a little more meaningful, and your CSS styling a little more generalized. This allows you to leverage common indexes between the links and the tabs below, as well as to define the style using a single CSS class. Then you can easily scale the solution for any number of links and panels:

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/HcL2g/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="SideNav">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" id="link1">Print 1</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#" id="link2">Print 2</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pieces">
        <div id="panel1" class="panel">First Div</div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel">Second Div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* 
  #content, #SideNav, #pieces
  Same As Before
*/

.panel {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $("a[id^='link']").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = this.id.replace("link", "");
        $(".panel").hide();
        $("#panel" + index).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: With only slightly more comples jQuery/CSS selectors, it isn't even strictly necessary to define those numbered IDs, or the `panel` class; you can derive that info. from the markup structure as well, if you have a concern about that change.

Answer (score 1):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5tzj/)

a Basic example of what you want to achieve :

JS :

```
$('a').on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).text());
    if($(this).text() == "Print 1"){
        $('#1').show();
        $('#2').hide();
    }else{
        $('#2').show();
        $('#1').hide();
    }
});
```

putting an event on click of your anchors and then checking the value of the clicked anchor.

Comment: Can this be altered to use for more than 2 links/divs?

Comment: yes. but you need to use more complex codes like Stephen's answer did.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first link toggles the visibility of the first div and the second link toggles the second div

```
$('a').click(function() {
  var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
  $('#pieces div').eq(index).toggle();
}
```

And set `display:none` on the the second div

Answer (score 0):

You setup the click function for each of the anchors within the `#sideNav` container, prevent the default anchor tag function(`preventDefault()`, in case an `href` attribute is provided) and then execute what you want to do.

```
$('#sideNav a').click(function(e){

  // prevent default link event
  e.preventDefault();

  // use show()/hide() or toggle()
});
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.